# 全ての組み合わせのリストを作成したい

Tags: python

５文字のアルファベットでできた単語が並んだ（１語ずつ改行）テキストファイルがあります。別に与えられたｎ文字(5<=n)のアルファベットに含まれている文字を並び替えて作成できる５文字の単語が、テキストファイルの中に何個あるか調べよ、という問題です。
※並び替えの際、与えられたn個の文字は１度ずつ使えるものとします。

'abcdee'という文字列が与えられたと仮定します。
この６文字から５文字を選ぶ組み合わせ（順列）は７２０通りです。この７２０通りの組み合わせの内、テキストファイルに登場する単語はいくつかを答えます。

まずは正しく７２０通りの組み合わせリストを作りたいのですが、現在のコードでは２４０通りしか出てきません。ところが、仮定の文字列を一文字だけ変えて'abcdef'とし、'e'の重複を解消すると、正しく７２０通り表示されます。このことから原因は、二つの'e'をうまく区別させることができていないためだと考えています。
ここまでわかったのですが、いかにして'abcdee'のままで７２０通り表示させるかを考えて、スタックしています。ご教示お願いします。

python, jupyternotebook ともに最新のバージョンです。

```
s = 'abcdee'
word = ''
anagrams = []

def perms(letters, word, anagrams):
    if len(word) == 5:
        anagrams.append(word)
    else:
        for i in letters:
            new_word = word + i
            new_letters = letters.replace(i, '')
            perms(new_letters, new_word, anagrams)
    return anagrams

print(len(perms(letters, word, anagrams)))
```

Comment: コードは画像ではなく **文字のまま** 質問中に貼り付けてください。(質問は後からでも編集できます)

Comment: `new_s = s.replace(i, '')` だと全ての文字を変換してしまいます。なので、`new_s = s.replace(i, '', 1)` としてみて下さい。

Comment: ※追記
質問のコードを修正した関係で、metropolisさんのコメントとずれが生じています。コメントの"s"は"letters"と読み換えて下さい。
※追記２
cubickさんご指摘のコードを画像で共有するのをまたやってしまっております。どうもうまく作動しない時がありまして、恐れ入ります。コピペできないは承知しております。今回のみすでにご回答を頂いているのでご容赦下さい。

Answer (score 4):

[`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)を使うことで順列を取得できます。

```
import itertools
anagramlist = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations('abcdee')]
print(len(anagramlist)) # 720
```

なおリビジョン3の質問では`abcdee`となっていますが、リビジョン1では`caatro`となっていました。
画像でソースコードを添付されていて、いかなるimportも禁止でした。

下記はその内容に沿った回答となっています。

---

コメントと重複しますが若干解説を加えて回答します。

`new_s = s.replace(i, '')`で文字列`i`と同一の文字を消去してしまっているのが原因です。
(例えば`'caatro'.replace('a', '')` を実行すると 'ctro' が返ります)
文字の置換回数を1回だけに抑えたい場合は`replace`関数の第三引数に`1`を設定してください。

```
new_s = s.replace(i, '')   # 修正前
new_s = s.replace(i, '', 1) # 修正後
```

**サンプルコード**

```
s = 'caatro'
word = ''
anagramlist = []

def perm_s(s, word, anagramlist):
    if len(word) == 5:
        anagramlist.append(word)
    else:
        for i in s:
            new_word = word + i
            #new_s = s.replace(i, '')   # 修正前
            new_s = s.replace(i, '', 1) # 修正後
            perm_s(new_s, new_word, anagramlist)
    return anagramlist

print(len(perm_s(s, word, anagramlist)))
```

参考資料:

- 公式リファレンス[組み込み型#`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20replace#str.replace)
- [Pythonで文字列を置換する：replace(), re.sub()](https://uxmilk.jp/8662)